# Cannot fix tailwind component dropdown on laravel

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

Im sitting from 3 hours and cant still figure out what is wrong. Im kind of new in programming, but on back end. I pasted from tailwind component navbar and dropdown is automatically opened. I tried so many things, or I dont get how to make them or I dont know... Tried also alpinejs, but not working or im doing something wrong. [I added picture here to show this dropdown which is not closing and is opened always no matter what. Im trying to fix this using blades on Laravel.

```html
<!-- This example requires Tailwind CSS v2.0+ -->
<nav class="bg-gray-800">
  <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="relative flex items-center justify-between h-16">
      <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden">
        <!-- Mobile menu button-->
        <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white" aria-controls="mobile-menu" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
          <!--
            Icon when menu is closed.

            Heroicon name: outline/menu

            Menu open: "hidden", Menu closed: "block"
          -->
          <svg class="block h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
          </svg>
          <!--
            Icon when menu is open.

            Heroicon name: outline/x

            Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden"
          -->
          <svg class="hidden h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-1 flex items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start">
        <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex items-center">
          <img class="block lg:hidden h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-indigo-500.svg" alt="Workflow">
          <img class="hidden lg:block h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-logo-indigo-500-mark-white-text.svg" alt="Workflow">
        </div>
        <div class="hidden sm:block sm:ml-6">
          <div class="flex space-x-4">
            <!-- Current: "bg-gray-900 text-white", Default: "text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white" -->
            <a href="#" class="bg-gray-900 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium" aria-current="page">Dashboard</a>

            <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Team</a>

            <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Projects</a>

            <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Calendar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0">
        <button class="bg-gray-800 p-1 rounded-full text-gray-400 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white">
          <span class="sr-only">View notifications</span>
          <!-- Heroicon name: outline/bell -->
          <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9" />
          </svg>
        </button>

        <!-- Profile dropdown -->
        <div class="ml-3 relative">
          <div>
            <button type="button" class="bg-gray-800 flex text-sm rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white" id="user-menu-button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
              <span class="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
              <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="">
            </button>
          </div>

          <!--
            Dropdown menu, show/hide based on menu state.

            Entering: "transition ease-out duration-100"
              From: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
              To: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
            Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-75"
              From: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
              To: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
          -->
          <div class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg py-1 bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu-button" tabindex="-1">
            <!-- Active: "bg-gray-100", Not Active: "" -->
            <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="user-menu-item-0">Your Profile</a>
            <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="user-menu-item-1">Settings</a>
            <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="user-menu-item-2">Sign out</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Mobile menu, show/hide based on menu state. -->
  <div class="sm:hidden" id="mobile-menu">
    <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1">
      <!-- Current: "bg-gray-900 text-white", Default: "text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white" -->
      <a href="#" class="bg-gray-900 text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium" aria-current="page">Dashboard</a>

      <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Team</a>

      <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Projects</a>

      <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Calendar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Picture of the problem
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Tailwind UI doesn't provide the necessary scripts. You have to write the JS yourself. Easiest way:

Add Alpine.js

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.8.2/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
```

Make "Profile Dropdown" an alpine component

```
<!-- Profile dropdown -->
<div x-data="{show: false}" x-on:click.away="show = false" class="ml-3 relative">
```

Add a click event to the Profile Button

```
<button x-on:click="show = !show" type="button" class="max-w-xs bg-gray-800 rounded-full flex items-center text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white" id="user-menu-button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">...
```

Snippet (I just made the desktop version work.. So open in full page)

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.8.2/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>

<!-- This example requires Tailwind CSS v2.0+ -->
<div>
  <nav class="bg-gray-800">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between h-16">
        <div class="flex items-center">
          <div class="flex-shrink-0">
            <img class="h-8 w-8" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-indigo-500.svg" alt="Workflow">
          </div>
          <div class="hidden md:block">
            <div class="ml-10 flex items-baseline space-x-4">
              <!-- Current: "bg-gray-900 text-white", Default: "text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white" -->
              <a href="#" class="bg-gray-900 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Dashboard</a>

              <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Team</a>

              <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Projects</a>

              <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Calendar</a>

              <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Reports</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden md:block">
          <div class="ml-4 flex items-center md:ml-6">
            <button class="bg-gray-800 p-1 rounded-full text-gray-400 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white">
              <span class="sr-only">View notifications</span>
              <!-- Heroicon name: outline/bell -->
              <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9" />
              </svg>
            </button>

            <!-- Profile dropdown -->
            <div x-data="{show: false}" x-on:click.away="show = false" class="ml-3 relative">
              <div>
                <button x-on:click="show = !show" type="button" class="max-w-xs bg-gray-800 rounded-full flex items-center text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white" id="user-menu-button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
                  <span class="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
                  <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="">
                </button>
              </div>

              <!--
                Dropdown menu, show/hide based on menu state.

                Entering: "transition ease-out duration-100"
                  From: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                  To: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-75"
                  From: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                  To: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
              -->
              <div x-show="show" class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg py-1 bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu-button" tabindex="-1">
                <!-- Active: "bg-gray-100", Not Active: "" -->
                <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="user-menu-item-0">Your Profile</a>

                <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="user-menu-item-1">Settings</a>

                <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="user-menu-item-2">Sign out</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="-mr-2 flex md:hidden">
          <!-- Mobile menu button -->
          <button type="button" class="bg-gray-800 inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white" aria-controls="mobile-menu" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
            <!--
              Heroicon name: outline/menu

              Menu open: "hidden", Menu closed: "block"
            -->
            <svg class="block h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
            </svg>
            <!--
              Heroicon name: outline/x

              Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden"
            -->
            <svg class="hidden h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Mobile menu, show/hide based on menu state. -->
    <div class="md:hidden" id="mobile-menu">
      <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1 sm:px-3">
        <!-- Current: "bg-gray-900 text-white", Default: "text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white" -->
        <a href="#" class="bg-gray-900 text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Dashboard</a>

        <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Team</a>

        <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Projects</a>

        <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Calendar</a>

        <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Reports</a>
      </div>
      <div class="pt-4 pb-3 border-t border-gray-700">
        <div class="flex items-center px-5">
          <div class="flex-shrink-0">
            <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="ml-3">
            <div class="text-base font-medium leading-none text-white">Tom Cook</div>
            <div class="text-sm font-medium leading-none text-gray-400">tom@example.com</div>
          </div>
          <button class="ml-auto bg-gray-800 flex-shrink-0 p-1 rounded-full text-gray-400 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white">
            <span class="sr-only">View notifications</span>
            <!-- Heroicon name: outline/bell -->
            <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9" />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3 px-2 space-y-1">
          <a href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700">Your Profile</a>

          <a href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700">Settings</a>

          <a href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700">Sign out</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <header class="bg-white shadow">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900">
        Dashboard
      </h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <!-- Replace with your content -->
      <div class="px-4 py-6 sm:px-0">
        <div class="border-4 border-dashed border-gray-200 rounded-lg h-96"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- /End replace -->
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```